# Worksheet Range function in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Probably a very simple one, why cant i specify and range of cells in the below.

```
If Worksheets("Todaysbatch").Range("C2:C12") = "COOP_DAYEND" Then
FileCopy COOPTEMPLATES & COOPDAYEND, newdir & COOPDAYEND
```

When i specify 1 cell the code does exactly what i want

```
If Worksheets("Todaysbatch").Range("C2") = "COOP_DAYEND" Then
FileCopy COOPTEMPLATES & COOPDAYEND, newdir & COOPDAYEND
```

I want it to look through cells `C2:C12` on `Todaysbatch` worksheet and match the string `"COOP_DAYEND"`

Comment: You cannot equate a range of cells to a value.  you will need to loop the range and check each individually.

Comment: Would there just be one `COOP_DAYEND` in this range, is this why you mentioned `MATCH`? Or can more cells hold this value?

Comment: The COOP_DAYEND position could vary from C2:C12 dependent on a refresh of data that runs on each day. The spreadsheet copies data from anther sheet within workbook.

Comment: If above reply means only one cell hold this value you don't need to loop through your range. It looks like you want to just know if any cell in this range holds this value and then create a filecopy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Range("C2:C12)` returns an array. If you wanted to access that array you could loop it and see if that value exists.

Even easier, you could use the worksheet function `Match` to see if it is in your range.

I made the change @scottcraner pointed out, the way I had it would error out if it did not exist.

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match("COOP_DAYEND", _
  Worksheets("Todaysbatch").Range("C2:C12"), 0)) Then
    FileCopy COOPTEMPLATES & COOPDAYEND, newdir & COOPDAYEND
End If
```

Comment: Would `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Todaysbatch").Range("C2:C12"), "COOP_DAYEND")>0` be less hassle?

Comment: @Chronocidal for this small of a range maybe, but COUNTIF is slower than MATCH.

Comment: See @ScottCraners answer. I didn't test this out, this would cause an error if not found.

Comment: Thank you Scott Craner, Yor If Not IsError solution done the tirck

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thank you! You answered my first question on here and didn't scare me off =). You also have taught me a lot along the way of becoming a better programmer and for that, I'm truly grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Like my comment above, it seems you just want to know if your range holds ANY value `COOP_DAYEND`. If this is true you could try:

```
If [COUNTIF(Todaysbatch'!C2:C12,"COOP_DAYEND")] > 0 then
    FileCopy COOPTEMPLATES & COOPDAYEND, newdir & COOPDAYEND
End if
```